# Tic Tac Toe code doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

Im doing a tic tac toe game in xcode. this is my code

```
    - (IBAction)c1Button:(id)sender {
if ((status.text = @"X goes now"))
{
    c1.text = @"X";
    if ([c1.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
    {
        status.text = @"O goes now";
    }
    else
    {
        status.text = @"X goes now";
    }
}
else if ((status.text = @"O goes now"))
{
    c1.text = @"O";
    if ((c1.text = @"O"))
    {
        status.text = @"X goes now";
    }
    else
    {
        status.text = @"O goes now";
    }
}
}
```

When the first cell is clicked a X appears as it should. And the status label changes to O goes now. But the when the cell is clicked it still writes X instead of O. What is wrong?

Comment: Don't use "status text" to store "state"; keep that in a separate date structure.

Comment: do you know you have to use `==` for comparison?? `=` is assignment operator. and for object comparison, you have to use `isEqual:`

Comment: I'm wondering how this is related to Xcode.

Comment: I've wondered enough. It's not related. Removing.

Comment: because I'm doing it in xcode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `if` statement you assign as string instead of comparing it. This:

```
if ((status.text = @"X goes now"))
```

should be:

```
if ([status.text isEqualToString:@"X goes now"])
```

And the same goes for the second statement.

Also, it is a better idea to keep the state (as an integer or boolean) and not use the title to resolve the state each time.

```
#define X_TURN    0
#define O_TURN    1


// ....

if (turn == X_TURN)
{
    c1.text = @"X";
    status.text = @"O goes now";
    turn = O_TURN;
}
else
{
    c1.text = @"O";
    status.text = @"X goes now";
    turn = X_TURN;
}
```

Comment: But you cannot allow a player to use a square that's already been used , so the state needs to be kept in a 3x3 array of some sort.

Comment: @trojanfoe - I agree, just didn't want to make the answer too long.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably best that the OP learns about such things at his own pace.